# Class of a Class

Tags: class, excel, vba

I'm getting just killed trying to make a class of a class. I have shopped around the site and seen several examples but maybe because its 1:43 I am having a hard time understanding them.

I was successfully able to use a class to automate a huge data entry project at work. I created a class called catDist which is the category distribution of types of agricultural products a company could manufacture or sell.

catDist contains six properties:
  Private selfWorth As String
  Private Q1 As Double
  Private Q2 as Double
  Private Q3 as Double
  Private Q4 As Double
  Private activated As Boolean

They all have the standard get and let codes.

There are 48 possible categories. I have a module that creates 48 instances of them with 48 different values for selfWorth (e.g "Cottonseed", or "maize" etc), and sets Q1 through Q4 as 0 .  The module originally worked with a Userform that I could type in the values and hit enter. If it saw that I had entered a value inside a particular textbox (yes there were 48X4 textboxes) it would set activated to true and changes the relevant Q's to the values I entered.

WHAT I WANT TO DO NOW.

It was a great success. Now what I want to do is create a class called "Distributor". Each distributor class would have 4 collections have catDist objects. I can create the distributor class. I can create the catDist class. But for the love of God I can not figure out a way to set the corresponding distributor catDist property to the catDist value I used in the Set method.

```
Sub testRegist()
Dim registrant As testRegistrant
Set registrant = New testRegistrant

registrant.registNum = "Z000123"
'MsgBox (registrant.registNum)

Dim cowMilk As testcatDist
Set cowMilk = New testcatDist

cowMilk.selfWorth = "Cow Milk"
cowMilk.distribution = 4.6

registrant.testCat = cowMilk

Debug.Print registrant.testCat.selfWorth

End Sub
```

catDist Class

```
Private pselfWorth As String
Private pdistribution As Double

Public Property Get selfWorth() As String
  selfWorth = pselfWorth
End Property

Public Property Let selfWorth(name As String)
 pselfWorth = name
End Property

Public Property Get distribution() As Double
   distribution = pdistribution
End Property

Public Property Let distribution(dist As Double)
  pdistribution = dist
End Property
```

Registrant a.k.a distributor class

```
Private pRegistNum As String
Private pCatDist As testcatDist

Public Property Get registNum() As String
    registNum = pRegistNum
End Property

Public Property Let registNum(registration As String)
  pRegistNum = registration
End Property

Public Property Get testCat() As testcatDist
   testCat = pCatDist
End Property

Public Property Let testCat(cat As testcatDist)
   Set pCatDist = New testcatDist
   pCatDist = cat
End Property
```

Comment: show some code please :)

Comment: haha I was trying to avoid that. I will put a simplified version I used to try to test the concept.

Comment: if you read the best practice of posting here on SO youød see that you are expected to  post a short selfdescriptive correct code example. The reason for this is that it's a lot easier to help you if we can understand the concrete problem

Comment: Sorry about that. I wasn't really expecting anyone to help LOL Especially so quickly.

Comment: You guys are incredible. This Worked! Now I am going to try to take it to the next step and build a collection of catDist objects in the registrant class.

Answer (score 2):

The only problem I see is that you are using `Let` instead of `Set`. In VBA you use `Set` when assigning to objects.

When you write `registrant.testCat = cowMilk` (in your `Sub`), `testCat = pCatDist` (in the getter of `testRegistrant.testCat`) and `pCatDist = cat` (in the setter of `testRegistrant.testCat`) you are implicitly using `Let` (it's as if you had written `Let registrant.testCat = cowMilk`) instead of (explicitly) using `Set`.

So, if you write `Set registrant.testCat = cowMilk` in your test `Sub`, `Set testCat = pCatDist` in the getter and `Set pCatDist = cat` in the setter you should be good to go.

Also, in the same setter, the initialization of `pCatDist` isn't needed since you are passing `cat` to it in the next line.

And, as @GSerg (thank you) says, the signature of your setter should be `Public Property Set testCat(cat as testcatDist)` instead of `Public Property Let`.

Comment: Not only that, but also replace `Public Property Let testCat` with `Public Property Set testCat`.